# How to specify the folder when downloading a file with slelenium python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, path

Here's my code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait     
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By     
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

PATH = "driver\chromedriver.exe"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 

p = {"download.default_directory": "C:\\Users", "safebrowsing.enabled":"false"}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", p)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=PATH)

url = 'https://www.mergermarket.com/homepage'

driver.get(url)

download = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="__next"]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/button[1]')))
download.click()
```

I made some research but almost everyone recommende to use `download.default_directory` with  `ChromeOptions`. I did like you can see above but it didn't work. Well, the code work but my file is downloaded in download and not the path I specified in my code.

Comment: You need administrator privileges to makes changes to the users folder. Try a different directory.

Comment: Ohh I see, let's try that.

Comment: But if I want to makes changes to the users folder, it is possible ?

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can copy automatically downloaded file in author path with os or shutill librarie in python

Comment: It wont take all the file in download ? Because there is a lot of them in there

Comment: And furthermore, the name provided when downloaded is random so it's tricky

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).